# How do I select the columns of a table in databricks sql?

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I can use: show columns in table_name
but this does not allow me to use the output in a query?

This throws an error:

SELECT
*
FROM
show columns in table_name

Comment: Include the error please

Comment: Once you have "select", it doesn't like your "in". What are you trying to do? The SHOW command already gives you all the column names, so doing a "select from" won't provide you any more information.